# Perl: Force stacktrace for "can't call method on undefined"

Tags: perl, exception

I'm using Perl and Catalyst as Web-Framework.

How can I **globally** force a stacktrace if an exception like `Can't call method "XXX" on an undefined value...` is thrown?

Suppose the following code in your `Controller/Root.pm`

```
use DateTime;

sub test  :Local :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    my $now = DateTime->now(time_zone=>'local');
    my $tmp = undef;

    my $throwing = $tmp - $now; #this will throw an exception!
    $c->res->body("OK");
}
```

Opening `http://localhost:3000/test` throws of course the exception:

> Caught exception in MyApp::Controller::Root->test "Can't call method
>   "subtract_datetime" on an undefined value at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/DateTime.pm line 1619,  line 1003."

The stacktrace is missing!

**How can I force in such a case a stacktrace?**

I.e. I would like to get (not a real output, only composed by hand):

```
MyApp::Controller::Root::__ANON__('Can\'t call method "subtract_datetime" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/DateTime.pm line 1619, <DATA> line 1003.^J') called at /home/user/MyApp/script/../lib/MyApp/Controller/Root.pm line 114
MyApp::Controller::Root::test('MyApp::Controller::Root=HASH(0x20583b60)', 'MyApp=HASH(0x206e9140)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst/Action.pm line 65
Catalyst::Action::execute('Catalyst::Action=HASH(0x20668e88)', 'MyApp::Controller::Root=HASH(0x20583b60)', 'MyApp=HASH(0x206e9140)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst.pm line 1687
eval {...} at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst.pm line 1687
Catalyst::execute('MyApp=HASH(0x206e9140)', 'MyApp::Controller::Root', 'Catalyst::Action=HASH(0x20668e88)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Catalyst/Action.pm line 60
[ and the rest of the exception ...]
```

With this I know exactly that the exception was caused by the line 114 in Root.pm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if it works within Catalyst, but usually you can force a stacktrace by including the CPAN module `Carp::Always`, e.g. by writing somewhere in your program `use Carp::Always;` or starting the perl script with the `-MCarp::Always` switch.

Comment: Works fine with Catalyst

Comment: Just putting `use Carp::Always;` somewhere in the code didn't work. I tried it by adding this line as the first line in `MyApp.pm` (the catalyst main file).

But if I insert it in the starter script under `/script/myapp_server.pl` it's working. Why isn't it working when putting it direclty in MyApp.pm?

Comment: Probot, [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for this unrelated topic/follow-up question.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661617/perl-carpalways-not-working-in-catalyst-myapp-pm

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to replace the default signal handlers for `__DIE__` and `__WARN__`:

```
use Carp;
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { die Carp::longmess @_ };
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn Carp::longmess @_ };
```

This is essentially what [`Carp::Always`](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp%3a%3aAlways) does for you (but it is more thorough and safer).

If you only care about this in one section of your code, then use dynamic scoping to limit the effect:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;

warn "not affected 1";

foo();
bar("outside");

warn "not affected 2";

sub foo {
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { warn Carp::longmess @_ };
    warn "in foo";
    bar("inside");
}

sub bar {
    warn @_;
}
```

output:

```
not affected 1 at t.pl line 8.
in foo at t.pl line 17.
 at t.pl line 17
    main::foo() called at t.pl line 10
inside at t.pl line 22.
 at t.pl line 22
    main::bar('inside') called at t.pl line 18
    main::foo() called at t.pl line 10
outside at t.pl line 22.
not affected 2 at t.pl line 13.
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on how this is more thorough and safer than Carp::Always' approach?  Also, thank you for this answer, it's perfect for situations where you don't have control over what modules are installed on a system.